# Series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln \ln n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

Considering the convergence of series:

1. $A=\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}}$
2. $B=\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln \ln n}}$

I tried to use inequation $\ln n \le n, \forall n \ge 2$, but I hadn't any ideas.

Comment: Hint: rewrite the denominators in the form $e^{f(n)}$ for some $f(n)$ and compare with the two series $\sum_n 1/e^{\ln n}$ ($=\sum_n 1/n$) and $\sum_n 1/e^{2\ln n}$ ($= \sum_n 1/n^2$).

Comment: Have you considered Cauchy condensation? I haven't explored all the details, but you may find this approach fruitful.

Comment: I haven't ever know about Cauchy condensation. I will research it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithms, especially nested ones, to me suggest that [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) is a good idea. By Cauchy's test, the first series converges iff the following series does:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n}{(\ln(n\ln2))^{(n\ln2)}}}$$

Then, by the root test, this series converges since: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{2}{(\ln(n\ln2))^{\ln2}}\bigg) = 0$$

The second series may also be evaluated using Cauchy's condensation test, but it is a little bit more involved.

Comment: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

I have already found a answer for the $1^{st}$ series.

We have: $(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}=n^{\ln \ln \ln n}>n^2, \forall n>n_0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}}<\frac{1}{n^2}, \forall n>n_0$.

And, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is converged. Since, A is converged

Comment: Spot on! The second is a little harder to write in terms of $1/n^{f(n)}$ but again I'd suggest that you may find $1/e^{f(n)}$ helpful as a form for comparison.

Comment: Then, with the first series $(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n}=e^{\ln n . \ln \ln \ln n}>e^{2\ln n}=n^2, \forall n \ge n_0$. With the second series, $\ln n^{\ln \ln n}=e^{(\ln \ln n)^2}$. Now, how do we evaluate it to proof B converges?

Comment: What do you get in the comparison between $(\ln\ln n)^2$ and $\ln n$?

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you.